# Accessing SLDS in a Custom Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, slds

```
<messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    <html>
        <body **class="slds-align_absolute-center"**>
          <p> All this must be center aligned</p>
          <p> All this must be center aligned</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

I have tried including the SLDS Class but it doesn't reflect in my email template.
How can I access SLDS classes in custom visualforce email template?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the excerpt below from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_stylesheets.htm), it seems you will need to *explicitly* declare the style classes within the template so that they are rendered in the email that’s sent. This seems to make sense because the email sent out will not have reference to the styles unless it’s part of the body.

> Unlike other Visualforce pages, Visualforce email templates cannot use referenced page styles or static resources. Although the CSS appears to render in the email template preview pane, it does not appear the same to the recipients of your email. You must define your style using CSS within  tags.

So, your option is to either have the styles included in the template or declare those in a custom VF component and use it in the template.

> Although you cannot reference an external stylesheet in a Visualforce email template, you can place the style definitions within a custom component that can be referenced in other places.